# Python: append new dictionary to json file

Tags: python

I have an existing json file below and I want to append new dictionary to the json file.

```
{
    "company_id": 1,
    "company_name": "Google"
    "members": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "title": "Analyst",
            "age": "24",
        },
        {
            "name": "Dave",
            "title": "Developer",
            "age": "27",

        },
        {
            "name": "Jim",
            "title": "Manager",
            "age": "34",

        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried

```
        file_data = json.load(file)
        file_data.update(new_data)
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(file_data, file, indent=4)
```

**EDITED:**

New data is as below with dict type

```
new_data = {
    "company_id": 1,
    "company_name": "Google",
    "members": [
        {
            "name": "James",
            "title": "CEO",
            "age": "50"
        }
    ]
}
```

It adds the new data to the file but messes up the existing data. Here is the output.

```
{
    "company_id": 1,
    "company_name": "Google",
    "members": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "title": "Analyst",
            "age": "24"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dave",
            "title": "Developer",
            "age": "27"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jim",
            "title": "Manager",
            "age": "34"
        }
    ]
}{
    "company_id": 1,
    "company_name": "Google",
    "members": [
        {
            "name": "James",
            "title": "CEO",
            "age": "50"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want it the new member in the same company_id to be added within the members but it just creates another json after the exisiting one.

Comment: In what way does it "messes up the existing data"?

Comment: can you show new_data contents? what is the expected result?

Comment: Doing `seek(0)` messes up the data because textfiles are not suited to updating on place. Close the file after reading from it and reopen it for writing before dumping to it.

Comment: @BoarGules: Yes, I see. If the `update(new_data)` actually overwrites something and makes it smaller, there could be stuff left over when the file closes.

Comment: I see you've updated the question to show the output, but what is in `new_data`?

Comment: See my answer. You just need to append new members to the existing members list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to close the json file before you dump the updated datа:

```
with open("data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data.update(your_data)

with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

**Updated answer**

Probably you need to refer directly where you need to add the new data:

```
import json

new_data = {
    "company_id": 1,
    "company_name": "Google",
    "members": [
        {
            "name": "James",
            "title": "CEO",
            "age": "50"
        }
    ]
}

with open("data1.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data['members'] += new_data['members'] # <-- here

with open("data1.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

The `file.seek(0)` to rewrite an opened file works only if the new data is longer that old one. If the new data is shorter you will get the mess.

Comment: This works! I accepted your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I wanna give thumbs up but I don't have 15 reputations or something.

Answer (score 2):

It just looks like you should append the new members:

```py
file_data[‘members’] += new_data[‘members’]
```

instead of doing an update.

Comment: After I dump to the file, now I have a new one with added member and existing one. 
{
    "company_id": 1,
    "company_name": "Google",
    "members": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "title": "Analyst",
            "age": "24"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dave",
            "title": "Developer",
            "age": "27"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jim",
            "title": "Manager",
            "age": "34"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: {
    "company_id": 1,
    "company_name": "Google",
    "members": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "title": "Analyst",
            "age": "24"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dave",
            "title": "Developer",
            "age": "27"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jim",
            "title": "Manager",
            "age": "34"
        },
        {
            "name": "James",
            "title": "CEO",
            "age": "50"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Perhaps you should also follow the ideas of others and close the file after reading, and open again for write before writing.

Comment: Try the answer from Yuri. It looks like he has solved both problems.

Comment: I wanna give thumbs up but I don't have 15 reputations or something.

Comment: Ok, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it works for me:

```
your_data = {"d": 4}
with open("file.json", "r+") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    data.update(your_data)
    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```

Comment: The op's code adds to the file too... how does your approach solve the unclear problem of "messing up" the data?

Comment: I used a one line json file. If you are using the same example as in the question, update the dump as follows : `json.dump(data, file, indent=4)`